# How to search or append a word in text file using gedit and terminal commands only

Tags: command-line, bash, gedit

I have to calculate the time consumed in search and append operation in gedit text editor. I know that I can calculate time in any command operation by using prefix time in that command like `time ls` to calculate time in command `ls` . I can calculate the time in opening a file in gedit by command `time gedit filename.txt`. But how can I calculate time in searching and appending a word in a text file using gedit text editor?

Comment: Probably you will need to time manually. There is no way `time` can measure what is happening *within* a process. It only can see and time when a process starts and when it ends.

Answer (score 0):

Why use gedit in command line? gedit is mainly for user who prefer GUI rather than terminal.

If you want search or append to file in command line use:

1. use `grep` to search text:

```sh
grep search_text myFile
```

2. use `>>` to append to file:

```sh
echo "append-text" >> file
```